# Smooth structure on $S^1$ is unique

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I've stumbled upon this fact about different smooth structures on the spheres $S^n$, that for $n\leq 6$, there's only one structure, but for $n=7$ there's $28$. I was trying to look up some information, books, etc. about this, but found very little. It may be that I wasn't looking well enough, but I was hoping maybe you can help me with some resources, or maybe some ideas, how to prove this, for example for the easiest case at least, the circle $S^1$. My knowledge of differential manifolds is basic, I've been reading John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, sections 1-6.

One differentiable atlas on $S^1$ is stereographic projection. So, we'd like to prove that any other atlas is equivalent to this one. How do I approach this, and what literature do you suggest on the topic?

Comment: This follows immediately from the classification of smooth 1-manifolds (all connected 1-manifolds are diffeomorphic to exactly one of $\{(0,1),[0,1),[0,1],S^1\}$). See [here](http://www.math.boun.edu.tr/instructors/wdgillam/1manifolds.pdf), for instance.

Comment: @Kajelad The smooth structures are not really unique, they are only unique up to *diffeomorphism*. For example, $\mathbb R$ has a smooth structure determined by the single chart $\phi : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, \phi(x) = x^3$. This smooth structure is different from the standard smooth structure. Nevertheless your comment is worth to be an official answer.

Comment: @Kajelad Could you elaborate?